# Swap all images on page via multiple links JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, swap

Ok I have this so far and it works to an extent,

```
$('a').click(function(e) 
{  
   e.preventDefault();  
   var preFix = $(this).attr("href");
   $('img.swap').each(
       function() { this.src = this.src.replace('.gif', (preFix)+'.gif');
   }); 
});
```

This pulls through the 'HREF' link and adds it to the end of the image. The problem is when I click the first link it swaps the images just fine but the second time I click one of the 5 links the image breaks.

I'm guessing its because it is just adding the 2nd prefix at the end of the first. I have tried a few things but it just ends up breakin the whole thing.

There are two things i need it to do:

1) When you click one link then another I want to to remove the old prefix and tthe new one.

2) If the same link is clicked twice I need it to firstly add the prefix then just remove the prefix.

Many  Thanks

Comment: almost got something for you how is your first prefix formated? or is its something you can set init.

Comment: it begins just banner.jpg, then when I click the link it sends the content of the HREF to the end of the image so banner-bw.jpg.

Comment: i fixed my code below to reflect what you really need. i think :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: :-D

```
$('img.swap').each(function{
    $(this).data('current_image', this.src);
    //saves the default image in data
})
$('a').click(function(e){  
       e.preventDefault();  
       var preFix = $(this).attr("href");
       $('img.swap').each(
       function() { 
         if($(this).data('prefix') != prefix){
           this.src = $(this).data('current_image').replace('.gif', (preFix)+'.gif');
           $(this).data('prefix', prefix)
         }
         else {
           this.src = $(this).data('current_image');
           $(this).data('prefix', '')
         }
       }); 
});
```

`$(this).data(..)` stores a variable in that specific DOM element, than after doing that you can do boolean operations to chack it against the value you have :-)

It is more explained here:
[jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

**UPDATE**

and instead of using an a (anchor) tag use something else with a className like .changeIMG:

```
<span class='changeIMG' postfix='-bw'>Change to black and white</span>
```

and with css it can look like an anchor tag:

```
span.changeIMG {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: blue;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and then there is 2 changes in the code above:

`$('a').click(function(e){` become `$('span.changeIMG').click(function(e){`
and `var preFix = $(this).attr("href");` become `var preFix = $(this).attr("postfix");`

Comment: No unfortunatly this isn't working, its making the a link a click through, but I will have a look into the jQuery.data() thankyou.

Comment: When I click the link, it just sends me through to the page instead of adding the prefix to the image, I just changed all the prefix so it matched but still now luck

Comment: @John White add return false; just before the closing off of your click event.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is supposed to prevent that. ill make a fiddle to show it work

Comment: @maniator I have this code adding the prefix to the SRC but it is deleting the beginning of the image. E.G. banner.jpg is just becoming _bw.jpg not banner_bw.jpg.

Comment: Just tried to implement it but it isn't working again, it keeps linking through to the href page which is meant to be the prefix. :(

Comment: <a title="Black and White" href="-bw">Black &amp; White</a> It is literally the prefix i need added onto the end. But I also have say Black and Yellow ect.

Comment: try my changes above. it will release u from the burdens of the anchor tag :-)

Comment: The only problem there is it is not W3C valid and for this site it really has to be :/

Comment: so instead in each a tag set href='#' and use the class name to store the prefix. that will make it still valid and you can use `var preFix = $(this).attr("class");` to get the prefix

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking up so much of you time, I have changed it to using classes, but the code itself is not working :/ when I click the link nothing happens. :(

Comment: ok. can you please change you post above to exactly what you have and example os the new a tags you have and img tags?

Comment: Ok, it was my fault i was code blind and just a few capitals and missing () but its all fixed and working great!! thank you so much

Comment: Sorry just had a thought, if I wanted to add the prefix to the images as it does not but also to a certain css file, in this case color.css would that be possible?

Comment: yes. make another question about adding css i would be glad to answer it. but for now i think i have sufficiently answered your question here.

Comment: on stackoverflow you put a checkmark next to what you think was the most correct answer. the more you validate answers the more people would want to help you with your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.swap").each(function(){
     var origSrc = $(this).attr("src");
     //original src can now always be accessed
     $(this).attr("origSrc",origSrc);
});

$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prefix = $(this).attr("href");
    $("img.swap").each(function(){
        var origSrc = $(this).attr("origSrc");
        var newSrc = origSrc.replace(".gif",prefix+".gif");
        $(this).attr("src",newSrc);
    });
});
```